# Javascript <--> XHTML troubles

Tags: javascript, xhtml

Sorry, I am reallllly new to Javascript/HTML. Okay so I am writing a program that shows the user a form. On that form they enter the price of an object they bought and click the shipping they want (standard or expedited). Then they click calculate and then it will show the S&H price, tax, and the total of the order. So the problem I am having is being able to communicate between the javascript code and the html form. We are also using very bacis techniques so I do not know how to do anything advanced. the code is here:

```
<head>
  <title>  </title>
        <script type="text/javascript">
<!--
    //this will prompt the user to enter the price(s) of their item(s) and add them together to get a 'total' of what they have input so far.

    function calc()
    {
        var iPrice = document.getElementById("iPrice").value;
        iPrice=parseInt(iPrice);
        if(iPrice <=0)
            alert("Please enter a number greater than 0");

        var shipMeth=document.getElementById("shipMethS").checked;

        var shippingPrice;
        if(shipMeth)
            {
                if(iPrice<0 && iPrice <25)
                    shippingCost =4.50;
                else if(iPrice <50)
                    shippingCost=7;
                else
                    shippingCost=10.25;
            }
        else
            {
                if(iPrice<0 && iPrice <25)
                    shippingCost =9.50;
                else if(iPrice <50)
                    shippingCost=12;
                else
                    shippingCost=15.25;
            }   
        shippingCost=parseFloat(shippingCost);
        var tax = iPrice*.06;
        tax=parseFloat(tax);
        var totalPrice=iPrice+shippingCost+tax;
        document.getElementById("totalPrice").value=totalPrice;


    }

    -->
    </script>
```

```
 <body>
<form>
    <p><label> Price: $
        <input name="iPrice"id="iPrice"type="text"size="25"/>
    </label>
    </p>

    <p>Shipping Method (Please only select one)</p>

    <p><Label>Standard
        <input name="CB"type="checkbox"value="Standard"id="shipMethS"/>
        </label>
       <label>Expedited 
        <input name="CB"type="checkbox"value="Expedited"id="shipMethE"/>
        </label>
    </p>

    <p><label>S&H Charges:
            <input name="S&H Charges" type="text" size="25" readOnly />
        </label>
    </p>

    <p><label>Tax (@6.00%):
            <input name="taxCharges" type="text" size="25" readOnly />
        </label>
    </p>

    <p><label>Total Price:
            <input name="totalPrice" type="text" size="25" value="totalPrice" readOnly />
        </label>
    </p>
    <p>
            <input type="button"value="Calculate"onClick="calc()"/>
            <input type="reset"value="Clear"/>
    </p>







</form>
```

Comment: this isn't valid xhtml

Comment: `TypeError: document.getElementById('totalPrice') is null`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<input name="totalPrice" type="text" size="25" value="totalPrice" readOnly />
```

needs to be

`<input id="totalPrice" name="totalPrice" type="text" size="25" value="totalPrice" readOnly />`

if you want to use "getElementById"
`document.getElementById("totalPrice").value=totalPrice;`

Then add the other fields at the end of the function:

```
document.getElementById("taxCharges").value=tax;
```

`document.getElementById("shCharges").value=shippingCost;`

You definitely don't need the comment tag in the script, but it shouldn't hurt anything. It looks like you could use more validation to make sure that there is a number in the input.

Comment: I made the change you said to the total price and that is working! thanks. However, I have also added           document.getElementById("tax").value=taxCharges;
         document.getElementById("shippingCost").value=shippingCharges;         to the end of the function and made the same change (<input id="shippingCharges" in the form but the shippipng charges and the tax charges is not updating when calculated.

Comment: Double check that your ids and getElementById fields are the same.  In your comment you're calling getElementById using "shippingCost", but the input has id "shippingCharges" - they must be exactly the same.

Comment: Oh i thought you can just set it to whatever you want. fixed it and now working, thanks man! By the way, is there any way to error check when using a form? Like if I type in a -1 in the price can I use an alert to say "Enter a positive number" then have them re-enter?

Comment: By the way, is there any way to error check when using a form? Like if I type in a -1 in the price can I use an alert to say "Enter a positive number" then have them re-enter?

Comment: There are many techniques to used for validation.  My fav is using regex - check out [w3schools](http://www.w3schools.com/html/html_form_attributes.asp), specifically the pattern attribute.  I also use [Regexr](http://www.regexr.com) for regex building.

Comment: ahh, thank you man! Also one thing, When submit is pressed on my form I have to display all the data in the form on the document. I have tried using <form onsubmit="showDoc()"> and having the function showDoc() print out everything but for some reason that is not working.

Answer (score 0):

You  are missing many things to make this works if this you are saying this the whole thing, see all of the changes I have done to it.

```
<html>
<head>
      <title>  </title>
 <script type="text/javascript">
<!--
        //this will prompt the user to enter the price(s) of their item(s) and add them together to get a 'total' of what they have input so far.
-->

        function calc()
        {
            var iPrice = document.getElementById("iPrice").value;
            iPrice=parseInt(iPrice);
            if(iPrice <=0)
                alert("Please enter a number greater than 0");

            var shipMeth=document.getElementById("shipMethS").checked;

            var shippingPrice;
            if(shipMeth)
                {
                    if(iPrice<0 && iPrice <25)
                        shippingCost =4.50;
                    else if(iPrice <50)
                        shippingCost=7;
                    else
                        shippingCost=10.25;
                }
            else
                {
                    if(iPrice<0 && iPrice <25)
                        shippingCost =9.50;
                    else if(iPrice <50)
                        shippingCost=12;
                    else
                        shippingCost=15.25;
                }   
            shippingCost=parseFloat(shippingCost);
            var tax = iPrice*.06;
            tax=parseFloat(tax);
            var totalPrice=iPrice+shippingCost+tax;
            document.getElementById("totalPrice").value=totalPrice;


        }
        </script>  
</head>

<body>
<form>
    <p><label> Price: $
        <input name="iPrice" id="iPrice" type="text" size="25"/>
    </label>
    </p>

    <p>Shipping Method (Please only select one)</p>

    <p><Label>Standard
        <input name="CB" type="checkbox" value="Standard" id="shipMethS"/>
        </label>
       <label>Expedited 
        <input name="CB" type="checkbox" value="Expedited" id="shipMethE"/>
        </label>
    </p>

    <p><label>S&H Charges:
            <input name="S&H Charges" type="text" size="25" readOnly />
        </label>
    </p>

    <p><label>Tax (@6.00%):
            <input name="taxCharges" type="text" size="25" readOnly />
        </label>
    </p>

    <p><label>Total Price:
            <input id="totalPrice" type="text" size="25" value="totalPrice" readOnly />
        </label>
    </p>
    <p>
            <input type="button" value="Calculate" onClick="calc()"/>
            <input type="reset" value="Clear"/>
    </p>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: It does not work when I take away the comment because I need that. Every program we did before this needed it to be inside the comment. I also now used spaces in between the attributes.

Comment: your comment start and end were in the wrong place, I just fixed the answer

Comment: yeah there are still mistakes in my code

Comment: would you post the complete html file, I am assuming your posted a partial  part of the file

Comment: this is the full html file. All it needs to do is show a form and the javascript reads in the price and shipping that the user has selected and calculates the full shipping total, the tax as well as the total.

Comment: see my updated answer, you are missing several tags, this should work. did you intent to have the S&H Charges and theTax to be readOny